# backing up .thumbnails powershell

Tags: powershell, copy, backup, thumbnails

I have written a backup script, which backs up and logs errors. works fine , except for some .thumbnails, many other .thumbnails do get copied!

of 54000 Files copied, the same 480 .thumbnails do not ever get copied or logged. i will be checking the attributes however i feel the copy-item function shouldve done the job. Any other recommendations are welcome as well, but please stay on topic, thx!!!!
here is my backUP script

```
    Function backUP{ Param ([string]$destination1 ,$list1)
    $destination2 = $destination1
                              #extract new made string for backuplog
                            $index = $destination2.LastIndexOf("\") 
                            $count = $destination2.length - $index
                            $source1 = $destination2.Substring($index, $count)
                            $finalstr2 = $logdrive + $source1

    Foreach($item in $list1){

     Copy-Item -Container: $true -Recurse -Force -Path $item -Destination $destination1 -erroraction Continue 
     if(-not $?)
     {
      write-output "ERROR de copiado : " $error| format-list | out-file  -Append "$finalstr2\GCI-ERRORS-backup.txt"
      Foreach($erritem in $error){
      write-output "Error Data:" $erritem.TargetObject  | out-file -Append "$finalstr2\GCI-ERRORS-backup.txt"
              }
      $error.Clear()
         }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `backUP` function is receiving `.thumbnails` files in `$list1`? If the files are hidden, then [`Get-ChildItem`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) will only return them if the `-Force` switch is used.

As for other recommendations, `Robocopy.exe` is a good dedicated tool for performing file synchronization.

Comment: hey emperor, it is recieving .thumbnails cause other  .thumbs are copying ok, it would appear i dont have rights to this particular  folder as i have checked.   As for robocopy, i will be integrating it into this script, but i like the error capabilities in powershell

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly permissions to the thumbnails folder, i had not.

that set, script worked fine!